# How to move all contents inside a windows folder link

Tags: ubuntu

My windows install on my dual boot has been corrupted... I need to backup certain files. I am currently trying with Nautilus and Dolphin to make a backup of "My Documents" and a few other folders. My documents is a "link" and when I copy it in ubuntu I merely get a link pointing to the other partition. How can I copy the actual contents of a linked folder, as well as the contents of any linked folders contained within? (recursive linked directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be severe overkill, but sometimes I go for a shotgun approach I know works.

Use two instances of tar -- one to create an archive and the second to restore it.

```
$SOURCE=/windows/whatever
$DEST=/tmp

tar --dereference -vcf - $SOURCE | (cd $DEST ; tar xf -)

The `--dereference` tells tar to follow symbolic links to the actual files they point to.
```

Comment: If anyone has a GUI way of doing this I'd appreciate it.. but for now this is good. Thanks

Comment: No problem ... glad it works for you.  The power of the command line is doing things GUIs can't :)